# How to validate subprocess.check_output()?

Tags: python

I am executing commands through subprocess.check_output() because i want the o/p of it to be stored in a buffer.

Now, while doing this if command gets failed or if there is any error then it is causing problem for my whole application.

What i want is, even if command fails it should just print and go on for next instruction.

Can anybody help me to solve it?

Below is the sample code.

```
from subprocess import check_output
buff=check_output(["command","argument"])
if buff=="condition":
    print "Do Some Task "
```

Comment: Why can't you just catch the exception `check_output()` raises?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use the [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method on a `Process` instance.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
proc = Popen(["command", "argument"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate() # Blocks until finished
if proc.returncode != 0: # failed in some way
    pass # handle however you want
# continue here
```

Comment: Not really a better way... `subprocess.check_output` will raise an exception for where the return value is non-zero itself and return the output from the subprocess as a string. No need to check the return code or manually raise an exception if you want to handle the normal case elsewhere in the program.

Comment: Does `check_output` concatenate the output of `stderr` and `stdout`?

Comment: If you pass `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to it, then yes

Comment: @BrendanMolloy : i tried using Popen, it is working but i don't want that way, because i want to store the o/p of commands into a buffer.
So i guess i will have to use subprocess.check_output() with try and exception method

Comment: Well, `out` and `err` in my answer have the stdout and stderr output of the command too, but if it's more elegant to do it another way, go for it! :D